# How can one disable the upper and lower scroll overflow bounds

Tags: html, css, html5, user-friendly, gui

I'm designing a website with a dark theme using HTML and CSS, but whenever I scroll up or down past the elements on the page the white background is extremely jarring. I've programed but I'm new to web development, so I'll try my best to articulate this issue in detail.

I have a header and a footer as normal, but I don't want either to follow the user's scroll (not fixed nor sticky positioning). The header should look like this: [image: Unscrolled header]

The header looks like the above image most of the time unless I'm scrolling up, then it looks like this:
[image: Scrolled Header]

Same with the footer:
[image: Unscrolled Footer]

Scrolling downward:
[image: Scrolled Footer]*I added the dotted line so the white background is visible

Ideally there is a way to prevent that white boundary from appearing when scrolling, but if not, is there at least a way to change the color such that it appears less jarring to the user?

Comment: I think you could solve this with just a background-color?  Have you tried that?  FYI, this would probably be better answered in the StackOverflow forum.